# Rails model design

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I want to create a model similar to reddit where users can upvote or downvote a link or article.  I am having trouble wrapping my head around this:  how do I made my models so that a user can like vote up or down a link only once and be able to change their mine (switch to a downvote) but never be able to vote multiple times no matter how much time has passed/logging out does not matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**has_many :through**

You'd create something like this:

```
#app/models/post.rb
Class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :votes do
      def user(user)
         find_by user_id: user.id
      end
   end
   has_many :voters, through: votes, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "user_id"
end

#app/models/vote.rb
Class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :post
   belongs_to :user
end

#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :votes
   has_many :posts, through: :votes
end
```

Standard [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) relationship - giving you the ability to use a `join model` to associate two or more *other* models together:

[image]

--

**User**

This would allow you to call the following:

```
#app/views/posts/show.html.erb
<% if @post.votes.user(current_user).present? %>
    <% link_path = @votes.votes.user(current_user).value == "up" ? vote_down_path : vote_up_path %>
    <%= link_to "Vote", link_path %>
<% else %>
    # empty vote link
<% end %>
```

The tricky bit is to associate a single vote with a single user - hence why I included an [ActiveRecord Association Extension](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) for your `votes` association

Answer (score 0):

You can use relationships to capture this...

- An Article has many votes
- A Vote belongs to a User
- A Vote has one article
- An article has many voters (users) through Votes but they must be unique. (validation rule)